# Which Controls will used to create Active X controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, activex, controls

Existing application in Java, Present we developed in .net.

Comment: Neither is 'in', I had fixed it - you overwrote my edit. Not your fault though.

Comment: @Drop Yeah, could you rephrase your question?

Comment: The question is totally unclear. Do you have an already-authored ActiveX control that you simply want to load in a HTML page? Or do you want to create a whole *new* ActiveX control? ActiveX and the language used on the server have absolutely zero to do with each other...

Comment: How does it work in the existing application? Do you just need a way to include an `<object>` tag referring to your ActiveX control?

Comment: Thanks, Can I include in .aspx design mode?

Answer (score 0):

you dont use HTML to create ActiveX. html only says how to display data on the web page

and.. your question is not clear...

Comment: Thanks, Which controls are comfortable in asp.net  to create Active X controls.